# Click button to reveal & hide content based on which button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have created two DIV's with 'Click me' buttons. When user clicks buttons a hidden DIV slides up and down. (I have used the .slideToggle();  method)

I need the DIV's to slide up independently of each other and not at the same time as they currently do now.

please see demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/manidf/AetnV/**

I have looked around for answers found these but not much help, http://bit.ly/fMn4JM and http://bit.ly/fuwA2U

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated Thanks
Manny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/AetnV/72/

Comment: You should then remove that +1 :) since it's @Manny's CSS. I have just modified his js.

Answer (score 0):

You're click event handler tells the class main_image to slide.

```
$(".main_image .block").slideToggle();
```

given that both your divs have the main_image class, they will act the same when either button is clicked.

Comment: This would've been better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

They're both happening because you're telling them both to pop up (as $(".main_image .block").slideToggle(); matches both sliding elements)

This should fix it as it selects only the sliding panel after the clicked link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Show Banner
    $(".main_image .desc").show(); //Show Banner
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0.85 }, 1 ); //Set Opacity


    //Toggle Teaser
    $("a.collapse").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("show");
    });


});//Close Function
```